# What is the difference between script and a make file?

Tags: makefile

I found they are all configuration file for compiling in MCU, but when and where to use which?

Answer (score 2):

A script is an interpreted computer program. That is, a program that can be executed by another program (an executable called an interpreter) without first being translated into another language. A script written in a particular language needs an interpreter that understands that language.

A makefile is a script. It is interpreted by some version of Make. The language of makefiles is designed to be used in build systems, invoking shell commands to build files out of other files. It can do other things, but generally not as easily as other languages that are more general or designed with those things in mind.

Where and when to use which tool is a very broad question. Broadly speaking, Make is a good tool for building files from other files, and keeping them up to date. Other languages may be better for other purposes, such as computation, stream editing or regular expression handling.

Comment: Nice answer. I would probably have added something about dependency graphs and timestamp comparisons, plus a typical example of a make rule.

Answer (score 0):

[Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128940/beta)'s answer is perfect. Just to give a glimpse of make, a good analogy could be a chef. When asked to cook a meal (the goal) it reads a cookbook (the makefile), identifies the ingredients (files), the proper order of operations and their description.

An important aspect of make is that it compares last modification times of files to decide whether a specific file is up-to-date or shall be rebuilt. A typical makefile contains a series of rules (which order usually does not matter) like this:

```
target_file: prerequisite_file_1 prerequisite_file_2 ...
    recipe_line_1
    recipe_line_2
    ...
```

(where each recipe line starts with a tab). This part tells make that `target_file` depends on `prerequisite_file_1`, `prerequisite_file_2`... That is, if `target_file` is needed to accomplish the goal, make will first decide whether it must be rebuilt or not:

- If it does not exist make will of course try to build it.
- If it exists already make will compare its last modification time with that of the prerequisite files. If `target_file` is older than one of the prerequisites, make will try to rebuild it.

If `target_file` must be rebuilt make will pass each recipe line to the shell (separate shells) which execution is supposed to build it (but make has no way to check this, it is your responsibility to write sound recipes).

Note that all this is recursive: if a prerequisite file is missing make will search for another rule that builds it. And if a prerequisite file exists but a rule also exists for which it is the target, make will check that it is up-to-date before building `target_file`. And it will first build missing or outdated prerequisite files before the top-level target file.

It is a bit like if the recipe in the cookbook was referring to a composite ingredient (let's say a sauce) that has its own separate recipe in the same cookbook.

The main differences with a naive shell script that would also describe the build process of a project is thus that the shell script would probably always rebuild everything while make will rebuild only what needs to be. Bonus: most make implementations are also capable of parallelisation: knowing what depends on what make can also discover what must be serialized and what could be done in parallel. On a multi-core computer, for large projects, the speed-up factor can be significant.